# why does this regex does not match?

Tags: regex, qregexp

Why does the following code does not match?
the expression is not that difficult and online regex tester also state that it should work. Am i doing something wrong with the escapes?

```
  QRegExp rex("(.*?)(\\d+\\.\\d+)_(\\d+\\.\\d+).*?");
  QString fileName("tile_10.0000_47.3100_0.1_.dat");

  if (rex.indexIn(fileName)>=0) {
    // ...
  }
```

Comment: Maybe `rex("([^_]*)_(\\d+\\.\\d+)_(\\d+\\.\\d+)")` will work as you need? Or even `rex("^([^_]*)_(\\d+\\.\\d+)_(\\d+\\.\\d+)")` if you need to match from the start of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QRegExp` does not support lazy quantifiers, so `*?` does not work here. Also, the `.*?` at the end of the pattern does not match any text, it can safely be removed.

I suggest replacing the first `.*?` with `([^_]*)_` pattern (*0+ chars other than `_` and a `_` right after them*) to get to the first `digits.digits` text:

```
rex("([^_]*)_(\\d+\\.\\d+)_(\\d+\\.\\d+)")
```

Or, if you need to match the data from the start of the string, prepend the pattern with `^` (start of string).

Answer (score 0):

One possile change could be:

```
(.*?)(\d+\.\d+)_(\d+\.\d+)_(\d+\.\d+)_\..*
```

Which is very strict to your example.

And here one which accepts any sequence of numbers followed by underscores till file extension.

```
(.*?)((\d+\.\d+)_+)\..*
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can also change quantifiers behaviour with `QRegExp.setMinimal()` to make them non-greedy by default and with a little change to your pattern:

```
QRegExp rex("(.*)(\\d+\\.\\d+)_(\\d+\\.\\d+)(\\D.*|$)");
rex.setMinimal(true);
```